# Assemble - page titles in Pages collection

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, assemble

On the [Pages](http://assemble.io/docs/Pages.html) bit of the assemble.io docs, under **Using YFM with the page variable**, it has this:

```
<ul>
    {{#each pages}}
    <li><a href="#">{{../page.title}}</a></li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

suggesting this will output the title (from each page's YFM) - if I paste that code into the top of example.hbs from the [examples project](https://github.com/assemble/boilerplates) it just outputs this (and I see the same thing in my own project):

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Examples</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Examples</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Examples</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Examples</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Examples</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the documentation has been updated since you posted this question. The correct handlebars code should be...

```
<ul>
  {{#each pages}}
    <li><a href="#">{{title}}</a></li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

This is saying that for each `page` in the `pages` collection, write out an anchor tag that uses the `title` property on the current `page` within the loop.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Weirdly that doesn't work for me, it outputs nothing? Should I update anything?

Comment: I downloaded assemble-bootstrap and dropped your code into index.hbs and it outputs empty anchor tabs

Comment: I meant tags, not tabs

Comment: @jonschlinkert or I will take a look and see what's wrong.... Also... just to make sure, do the pages have a `title` property in the yaml front matter?

Comment: Yes - using assemble-bootstrap, all pages seem to have titles. Does this (bootstrap) work as described above for you? I just pasted in doowb's code

Comment: See here: https://github.com/assemble/assemble-bootstrap/blob/3.0.0-wip/docs/components.hbs#L2-L4. Then here: http://assemble.github.io/assemble-bootstrap/components.html. The subhead is where the title and lead render, and they work correctly there. Are you wrapping the page in another tag by any chance? Or are you using this as a partial?

Answer (score 0):

The data for each page is exposed via the `data` object. Updated code below.

```
<ul>
  {{#each pages}}
    <li><a href="#">{{ data.title }}</a></li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```